# View website icon cross-domain

Tags: php, gd, favicon

I have a hopefully very quick request for assistance, and am hoping it will even work. I am happy to use GD if it is needed.

I have users who will be using their account login in the internal intranet as their homepage, we are going to allow them to customize some favorites making it easier to have access to their pages no matter what station they use.

Doing this isn't a problem, however I am interested in Generating a button for each that would show the icon (using the favicon from each website) as well as their custom text on each.

I have used Google and haven't really found anyone even asking to do this outside of tabs in firefox and internet explorer troubleshooting. I hope its easy, let alone possible. If not, I apologize for wasting your time.

Thanks as always guys!

Answer (score 1):

Favicons are defined one of 2 ways, the existence of favicon.ico or a specification within a meta tag on the index page.

First, simply grabbing the favicon.ico:

```
$icon = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/favicon.ico');
file_put_contents('/some/local/path/google-favicon.ico',$icon);
```

If this shows up a 404 (file_get_contents returns false, or $icon is false), then you can do something like:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.quotes.uk.com/');
preg_match_all('/<link.*rel="icon".*href="([^"]+)"/i',$content,$out);
$icon = file_get_contents($out[1][0]);
file_put_contents('/some/local/path/quotesuk-favicon.png',$icon);
```

So my examples are simplified approaches. Take this one step further:

- Verify the results are coming back OK (logic)
- Utilize the mime-type, some favicons are PNG; you can use cURL to capture the headers or [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/mime_content_type) if mime magic is enabled to guess (errr [`fileinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) if available)
- See more ways of including a favicon here: http://www.quotes.uk.com/web-design/meta-tags.php (Section "Favicon Meta Tags")
- Consider beefing up my regex, or use another method entirely (SimpleXML?) since it doesn't take into consideration the order of the attributes (which can vary)
- Don't write your code as inconsiderate as mine is

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and let you know how I go, I appreciate your time on the matter :)

Comment: @Tarquin any luck? what was the final solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looking further, it appears as if its not as simple as I wanted, although I rather cache it locally. So far the solution I have found is to use the following service from google, again if anyone has a better solution, please do let me know as this is not how I would like to resolve the issue. Thanks!

http://www.google.com/s2/u/0/favicons?domain=www.stackoverflow.com